# Upload amazon s3

Tags: php, upload, cloud, amazon-aws

Estou com uma dúvida, fiz um pequeno script php para fazer upload de arquivos para dentro do meu bucket e preciso que todo e qualquer arquivo contido nele, seja acessado apenas através de uma url. Como posso fazer isso? via código ou configuração no meu bucket mesmo?

Preciso disso pois o sistema que estou desenvolvendo, tem como requisito que os arquivos e videos sejam acessados apenas dentro da área do usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém precise, consegui na documentação da amazon as informações de como fazer tais restrições, basta adicionar a bucket policy abaixo no seu bucket:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Descricao aqui",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nomebucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.urlaqui.com/*",
                        "http://urlaqui.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```